# EditText to String returns Null

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

As title says, when i execute this app, WebView connects to "https://null/"
insted of the string i put on the EditText, i cant figure out the problem

MainActivity activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText web;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    web = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.web);
    String webstr = web.getText().toString();
    Intent int2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WebView.class);
    int2.putExtra("123", webstr);
    Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WebView.class);
            v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

  }
}
```

WebView Activity

```
public class WebView extends AppCompatActivity {
private android.webkit.WebView webView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String web1 = intent.getStringExtra("123");
    webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl("https://" + web1);
    Toast.makeText(WebView.this, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

 } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the value from your `EditText` when you click the button, not within `onCreate`.

Also you're not using the same `Intent`, so you're not actually passing that value.

```
Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WebView.class);
        String webstr = web.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra("123", webstr);
        v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You call wrong intent and with gettext at the wrong place here below you can see modified code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText web;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
web = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.web);


Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


  String webstr = web.getText().toString();
  Intent int2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WebView.class);
  int2.putExtra("123", webstr);
  v.getContext().startActivity(int2);
    }
});

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have placed the statement in 'onCreate()' method. Place it inside the 'Button.onClickListener'.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText web;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        web = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.web);
        Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String webstr = web.getText().toString();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WebView.class);
                intent.putExtra("123", webstr);
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

  }
}
```